# Extracting specific tag and attribute from HTML not working

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to extract the ticker symbols from this website: https://www.capitoltrades.com/trades?txType=buy&tradeSize=4&tradeSize=5&tradeSize=6&tradeSize=7&tradeSize=8&tradeSize=9&tradeSize=10&page=3

While the code below extracts ticker symbols, for some reason it is not extracting ticker symbols that are actually present on the website.

for example: my code says that these ticker symbols are present:
N/A
WFC:US
TSM:US
N/A
NYCB:US
N/A
BAC:US
BRK/B:US
FRC:US
N/A
AMZN:US
NVDA:US

However looking at the website this is what i see present:
PYPL:US
ANET:US
INTC:US
FDX:US ..... nothing from above matches.

I think the problem stems from the fact that there are multiple pages to scroll through on the same url.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

```
# import packages
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# create GET request for URL
URL = "https://www.capitoltrades.com/trades?txType=buy&tradeSize=4&tradeSize=5&tradeSize=6&tradeSize=7&tradeSize=8&tradeSize=9&tradeSize=10&page=3" 
r = requests.get(URL)

# Extracting specific tag and attrs for ticker symbols
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser') # If this line causes an error, run 'pip install html5lib' or install html5lib
tag = soup.find_all(["span"], attrs = {'class':'q-field issuer-ticker'})
for tag in tag:
    print(tag.get_text())
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to parse html page, use json data directly:

```
URL = "https://bff.capitoltrades.com/trades?page=3&pageSize=12"
data = requests.get(URL).json()

tickers = [d['asset']['assetTicker'] for d in data['data']]
print(tickers)

# Output
['ANET:US', None, 'ADSK:US', None, 'EPAM:US', 'ACN:US', 'ADSK:US',
 'TRTN:US', 'SEDG:US', 'ENTG:US', 'ZION:US', 'EPAM:US']
```

Comment: Does it solve your problem. Let me know.